# Bootstrap multiselect dropdown not showing when appended

Tags: javascript, html, css, append, adminlte

I have a dropdownlist from bootstrap (AdminLTE template) which allows me to do multiselect:

[image: picture of dropdown]

As seen here there is no problem when I hardcode the multiselect on my JSP but when I tried to use it on append, the dropdown is no longer showing:

[image: picture of appended dropdown]

Here is my code when appending on my JS file:

```
table.append(
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + codePA + '</td>' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="codePA" class="readonlyWhite" id="codeIGA" value="' + codePA + '" />' +
        '<td>' +
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible select-iga" multiple="" data-placeholder="Select IGA" style="width: 50%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">' +
        '<option value="1">IGA01</option>'+
        '<option value="2">IGA02</option>'+
        '<option value="3">IGA03</option>'+
        '</select>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<span class="label label-success">pending</span>' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="status" class="readonlyWhite" id="codeIGA" value="pending" />' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<div class="col-sm-10">' +
        '<input type="text" name="remarks" class="form-control no-border" id="remarks">' +
        '</div>' +
        '</td>' +
        '</tr>'
        );
 }
```

All of the other columns are working on my append it's only the select portion that's not showing/working at all.

Comment: Which library is being used for `multiselect` ?

Comment: I'm using plugins provided by AdminLTE template (css & js). I include the scripts (url to the plugins) on my jsp page.

Comment: can you try giving multiple="true",or just multiple,also check whether the script instantiated and included in jsp page